# Access violation when calling overridden function

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

```
class Element {
public:
    ElementTypes type = DOT;

    Element() {}
    Element(ElementTypes type) : type(type) {}

    virtual void Draw() { return; }
};
```

```
class Dot : public Element {
public:
    int x, y;

    Dot(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    void Draw() override {
        DrawCircle(x, y, 2.f, BLACK);
    }
};
```

```
class Drawing {
public:
    std::vector<Element*> Elements;

    void AddDot(Dot& dot) {
        Elements.emplace_back(&dot);
    }

    void Draw() { 
        for (auto element : Elements) {
            element->Draw();
        }
    }
};
```

For some reason, there is a crash when trying to call `element->Draw()`.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF66DDC1486 in geometry.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

I am using the function `AddDot` to add an element to the vector

Not using a pointer to the class, the `Draw` function is just not overriden.

Comment: `Elements.emplace_back(&dot);` is most likely a bug. You can't use `&` to store the address of a parameter passed to your function. The lifetime of the parameter ends and your storing the address of an object that no longer exists.

Comment: @drescherjm it will give me a compiler error if i remove the reference (cant convert from Dot to _Objty). is there some workaround to this?

Comment: You need to either allocate using `new Dot` or switch and `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Element>> Elements;` and `std::make_unique<Dot>`

Comment: @drescherjm That would be true if the parameter were passed by value. In this case it's passed by reference so taking the address doesn't immediately result in a dangling pointer. However, it's probably still the case that these pointers do become dangling, it just depends on where those references are coming from.

Comment: @Kyle good point. That part of the code is missing and I assumed it was some local variable.

Comment: Sometimes fixing a bug mistake the right way allows the compiler to spot MORE mistakes in the code. Don't feel disheartened if you made a change you know it correct and are rewarded with additional error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to your first Access Violation!
Do not panic.  :)

```
Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000
```

Access Violation + a location like 0x0000 (zeros) are likely just a `nullptr`.
Since you hold something like `std::vector<Element*> Elements;` it may be understandable where it comes from.

To add a new `Element` you'll need to actually allocate.
The usage of `Dot& dot` passes it by reference to an unknown location which isn't a good practice since you'll hit UB pretty fast (Or worse, heap corruptions).

To allocate a new element you'll need to do:

```cpp
std::vector<Element*> Elements;

Elements.push_back(new Element(/*Params here*/));
```

Since you don't have actually any expensive values in your class you may hold it by value instead:

```cpp
std::vector<Element> Elements
```

For the sake of simplicity do not go into why it should be value or pointer.
Combining it with Composition you may compose a drawable for the sake of simplicity of the vector:

```cpp
struct Drawable 
{
    Drawable(Entity* toDraw) :ToDraw(toDraw) {}
    ~Drawable() { if(ToDraw != nullptr) { delete ToDraw; } } 
    Entity* ToDraw; 
    void Draw(){ ToDraw.Draw(); } 
}
// Vector doesn't hold pointers anymore. 
// Passing Drawable& will not result in Undefined behavior but a copy or a move. 
std::vector<Drawable> toDrawVec; 
toDrawVec.emplace_back(new Dot());
toDrawVec.emplace_back(new Square());
toDrawVec.emplace_back(new Square());
```

Please focus on your learning and try to look for `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` and `RAII` (The technique used here).

---

The virtual functions do not play a role here since `Drawing` doesn't inherit `Element`.
I'd suggest making something like `Drawable` So any entity that needs to draw may inherit it.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually need the Dot Draw() to override the Element Draw(). Drawing class is just some place where i manage all the elements. Not using a pointer works fine, but the function is not being overrided. Anyways, i fixed it by using an unique_ptr.

Comment: @Simply he can;t have a vector of Element if he wants polymorphic behavior

Comment: @NeilButterworth There are few solutions to that, I won't go into them since OP clearly is somewhat of a beginner. I don't want to create too much complexity. 
Glad you found a solution Stephan! Best of luck.

Comment: @Simply there is no magic way of turning a base class object into a derived object

Comment: @NeilButterworth He can compose `Entity` from an Inner ``Drawable`` element and hold the Ptr inside. 
I didn't want to suggest ``unique_ptr`` and ``shared_ptr`` since he's clearly a beginner.   
This is not only about the answer being perfect - but being more practical to OP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed probably that `dot`, which address was added to the vector, no longer exists when you do the drawing. A typical case is if you initialise the `Drawing` in a function, using local objects that get destroyed when leaving the initialization function.

One way of solving it is to ensure that all the figures that are added in the `Drawing` are created on the freestone with `new`.  You'd still have to take care of their deletion later on.  This is error prone.

A better option would be to go for smart pointers instead of raw pointers. This makes sure that the object is kept alive as long as there are some smart pointers pointing to it, and that th object is destroyed once it's no longer used (hint:  work on Drawing's destructor.  Here the change:

```
class Drawing {
public:
    std::vector<shared_ptr<Element>> Elements;

    void AddDot(shared_ptr<Element> dot) {
        Elements.emplace_back(dot);
    }

    void Draw() { 
        for (auto element : Elements) {
            element->Draw();
        }
    }
};
void init (Drawing&d) {
    auto dt1 = make_shared<Dot>(10,30); 
    d.AddDot(dt1);
}
int main() {
    Drawing d; 
    init (d);
    d.Draw(); 
}
```

**[(Online demo)](https://ideone.com/K8xpij)**

The advantage is that you can safely transform `AddDot()` into a polymorphic `AddElement()` and avoid creating a new add function for every possible shape.

Another approach is not as sophisticated and robust as the smart pointer, but relatively easy to implement: take the dot that is passed as argument and make a copy that is owned (and later destroyed) by the `Drawing`.  Unfortunately, with your current code, it would be cumbersome as you'd need a different function for every subclass of `Element` that you would like to add (because their constructor may take different arguments and you don't want [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) to happen).  So you'd need to give `Element` a `clone()` function that returns a pointer to a newly created `Element` of the same type (this is the [prototype pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/prototype/cpp/example)).